# Serial Connection on Apple TV2

Tags: iphone, ios, tty

On the iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad I'm able to communicate with an external device via the dock connector (Pin 12/13). Now I'm trying to do the same thing on the Apple TV2. I already got the right pin assignment from [this picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/56083335@N00/5335526558/).

My problem is now that I'm missing the interface "/dev/tty.iap" on the ATV which I used on the iPhone to communicate with the dock connector. Is there a way to manual install this interface or could I use another interface which are already on the ATV?

Thanks in advance.